# mdadm.conf: mdadm -E --scan *vs* mdadm -D --scan, which is correct to use?

Tags: software-raid, mdadm

I have two questions:

1. It's not clear which flag to use when generating mdadm.conf.
   I've seen people and documentation use

   ```
   mdadm -E --scan
   ```

   I've also seen `mdadm -D --scan`.
   Which is correct to use?
   I'm on Ubuntu 18.04.3 LTS
2. They usually report similar information just in a different way but during rebuild of spare on my system I noticed they are different (RAID 5)

   ```
   root@xxxxx:~# mdadm -D --scan ARRAY /dev/md/imsm0 metadata=imsm UUID=29c041a7:85b67ead:18fe5dc4:4acac02a ARRAY /dev/md/Volume0 container=/dev/md/imsm0 member=0 spares=1 UUID=3fefef37:bf7ec5be:8aa0bf1f:695109bb
   root@xxxxx:~# mdadm -E --scan ARRAY metadata=imsm UUID=29c041a7:85b67ead:18fe5dc4:4acac02a ARRAY /dev/md/Volume0 container=29c041a7:85b67ead:18fe5dc4:4acac02a member=0 UUID=3fefef37:bf7ec5be:8aa0bf1f:695109bb
   ```

Comment: Have you seen this page (manpages.ubuntu.com)? This would may describe items best : http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/en/man8/mdadm.8.html It sounds like you have done some research... I also have read this https://linux.die.net/man/8/mdadm Very useful info. I am learning about it myself, I'm a linux newbee. Peace

Comment: I've already looked at man pages, didn't say anything